# Handlebars.js misses JSON data

Tags: requirejs, handlebars.js

I've got template file loaded by Require.js via this:

**main-app.js**

```
define([
        'backboneLoader',
        'handlebars',
        'text!templates/main.html',
        'text!appdata.json'
    ],
    function(
        Backbone,
        Handlebars,
        MainTemplate,
        AppData
    ) {
        "use strict";

        return Backbone.View.extend({
            initialize : function() {
                this.render();
            },

            render : function() {
                var template = Handlebars.compile(MainTemplate);
                var output = template(AppData);
                this.$el.append(output);
                console.log("appData:\n" + AppData);
                console.log("MainTemplate:\n" + MainTemplate);
                console.log("Output:\n" + output);
                    //smth extra
                return this;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

**MainTemplate (main.html)**

```
<ul>
    <li><b>Version:</b> {{version}}</li>
    <li><b>Author:</b> {{author}}</li>
</ul>
```

**AppData (appdata.json)**

```
{version: "0.0.1", author: "John Doe"}
```

*And output:*

```
<ul>
     <li><b>Version:</b></li>
     <li><b>Author:</b></li>
</ul>
```

*While expected output:*

```
<ul>
        <li><b>Version:</b> 0.0.1</li>
        <li><b>Author:</b> John Doe</li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong? Thank you!

**UPD:**
Problem solved. Here is updated **main-app.js:**

```
define([
        'backboneLoader',
        'handlebars',
        'text!templates/main.html!strip',
        'text!appdata.json'
    ],
    function(
        Backbone,
        Handlebars,
        mainTemplate,
        appData
    ) {
        "use strict";

        return Backbone.View.extend({
            initialize : function() {
                this.render();
            },

            render : function() {
                var template = Handlebars.compile(mainTemplate);
                var output = template(eval("(" + appData + ")")); //Object is expected by template(), not JSON.
                this.$el.append(output);
                console.log("appData:\n" + appData);
                console.log("template:\n" + mainTemplate);
                console.log("Output:\n" + output);
                    //smth extra
                return this;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Problem solved. I've just replaced:
var output = template(AppData);

with:
var output = template(eval("(" + appData + ")"));

Comment: Please don't use `eval`!  This is poor practice and is a security flaw, because if any arbitrary JavaScript is in the text, it will be evaluated.  Better to use `JSON.parse(appData)`.  You may need to include `json2.js` to add JSON support for older browsers (<=IE7): https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `AppData` is a string of JSON, not an actual Object.  Simply change from:

`var output = template(AppData);`

to

`var output = template(JSON.parse(AppData));`

You may need to include [json2.js](http://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) to add JSON support for older browsers (<=IE7).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [jsFiddle repro](http://jsfiddle.net/UM9x4/) of your template function, the template transformations seems working, the problem is probably located in the text! function in require.js code, try to debug the text! function.

Try also to add the !strip function when loading the template: 'text!templates/main.html!strip',

The documentation suggests it :`For HTML/XML/SVG files, there is another option. You can pass !strip, which strips XML declarations so that external SVG and XML documents can be added to a document without worry.`

Comment: Thank you for answer! But nothing helps. Still 'lurking' for reasons. Seems like something wrong with "text!AppData.json".